# Loading Images in SWT on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, image, macos, jar

I am developing a SWT java application and to set an image to a shell , i am using

```
static public Image IMAGE =new Image(MainClass.display,Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("image.png"));
shell.setImage(IMAGE);
```

This works fine if i run the application from eclipse but when i export it as a jar and try to run it ,I am getting an

```
exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument cannot be null
```

at the setImage() line.

All the images are in src folder of the project

I am using eclipse Luna on OS X 10.9.5

I am running the jar file from command line using

```
java -jar -XstartOnFirstThread App.jar
```

Also when i expand the jar file,i see all the files including the images in the same folder and there is no src folder

Comment: Your `getResourceAsStream` is probably not working. There are any number of similar questions already on SO about this.

Comment: but how is it working when i run it from eclipse

Comment: Yes and most of the existing questions are about exactly that problem.